# Multipart identifier error in Excel 2007 MS Query but not in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, excel-2007, ms-query

I have the following SQL code

```
SELECT pd1.Meter,
       pd1.BasicPool,
       pd1.RateClass,
       pd1.Flowdate,
       (SELECT upOrDownContract
        FROM   PipelineData pd
        WHERE  pd.id = pd1.sibling) AS DnK,
       match.Volume,
       (SELECT Name
        FROM   Pipeline P
        WHERE  P.id = ISNULL(pd2.pipelineID, t.PipelineId)) AS Pipeline,
       (SELECT Name
        FROM   Client C
        WHERE  C.id = t.ClientId)                           AS CounterParty
FROM   MatchingHistoryBothSides match
       LEFT JOIN PipelineData pd1
              ON match.type1 = 'PipelineDataVO'
                 AND match.id1 = pd1.ID
       LEFT JOIN PipelineData pd2
              ON match.type2 = 'PipelineDataVO'
                 AND match.id2 = pd2.ID
       LEFT JOIN TransactionDailyVolume dtv
              ON match.type2 = 'TransactionDailyVolumeVO'
                 AND match.id2 = dtv.ID
       LEFT JOIN [Transaction] t
              ON dtv.TransactionID = t.ID
WHERE  match.type1 = 'PipelineDataVO'
       AND ( match.type2 = 'PipelineDataVO'
              OR match.type2 = 'TransactionDailyVolumeVO' )
       AND pd1.flowDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
       AND pd1.LDCid = 75
       AND pd1.direction = 'Receipt'
```

It works fine in SQL Sever 2008 but gives `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "pd1.flowDate" could not be bound` in MS Query of Excel 2007. Can anyone explain where this code is going wrong?

Comment: Try `select top 1 Flowdate from PipelineData` in Excel. Can you also please post the error message in ful.

Comment: @Stoleg I posted the complete error message and where do suggest me to add `Top 1` in the above code?

Comment: Run my code instead of yours. It will show if the column exists / visible at all. case sensitivity is a good suggestion by @pnuts too.

Comment: @Stoleg I ran your code in excel and it worked

Comment: @pnuts for case senstive I change both occurances to pd1.flowDate and it didn't work

Comment: I found this [Microsoft Support Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/964009). I think it is the same case here too. What do you both think?

Comment: I tried that too and it didn't work. It should not be a case as they both are from 2 different tables

Comment: But that is for some Financial software by Microsoft not for Excel so I don't know if the issue is resolved in Excel 2007. Mine is Excel 2007 SP3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub queries in `Select` are not allowed in MS Query. Hence on removal of the the sub queries and making them as joins will work in MS Query. The following code works in MS Query

```
SELECT pd1.Meter,
       pd1.BasicPool,
       pd1.RateClass,
       pd1.FlowDate,
       pd.upOrDownContract AS dnk,
       match.Volume,
       p.Name              AS pipeline,
       c.Name              AS counterparty
FROM   Matchinghistorybothsides match
       LEFT JOIN Pipelinedata pd1
              ON match.type1 = 'PipelineDataVO'
                 AND match.id1 = pd1.ID
       LEFT JOIN Pipelinedata pd2
              ON match.type2 = 'PipelineDataVO'
                 AND match.id2 = pd2.ID
       LEFT JOIN Transactiondailyvolume dtv
              ON match.type2 = 'TransactionDailyVolumeVO'
                 AND match.id2 = dtv.ID
       LEFT JOIN [Transaction] t
              ON dtv.TransactionID = t.ID
       LEFT JOIN Client c
              ON c.id = t.ClientId
       LEFT JOIN Pipelinedata pd
              ON pd.id = pd1.sibling
       LEFT JOIN Pipeline p
              ON p.id = COALESCE(pd2.PipelineId, t.PipelineId)
WHERE  match.type1 = 'PipelineDataVO'
       AND ( match.type2 = 'PipelineDataVO'
              OR match.type2 = 'TransactionDailyVolumeVO' )
       AND pd1.FlowDate BETWEEN ? AND ?
       AND pd1.LDCid = 75
       AND pd1.direction = 'Receipt'
```