# Excel "The multi-part identifier could not be bound" When Using Parameters

Tags: sql, excel

I have a SQL query in Excel that will work just fine if I hard code the dates into the query. As soon as I try to change them to `?`'s it gives the error. I've used parameterized queries like this in loads of reports, so I'm not sure why this one is suddenly not working.

The full error is `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "cancel.arrival_date" could not be bound.` which pops up twice.

Here is my query with the `?` in it that gives the error:

```
SELECT cancel.reservation_number, (client.last_name + ', ' + client.first_name) AS 'guest_name',
        cancel.cancel_date_time, cancel.arrival_date,
        DATEDIFF(DAY, cancel.cancel_date_time, cancel.arrival_date) AS 'Days Out', cancel.cancel_reason, 
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM gbfol_head head
                        LEFT JOIN gbfol_det det ON head.folio_number = det.folio_number
                        WHERE cancel.reservation_number = head.source_id
                                AND head.folio_type <> 'b' AND det.posting_code = 'admn') THEN
            'ADMN Charged'
        ELSE
            'No ADMN Fee'
    END AS 'ADMN',
cancel.amount, cancel.cancel_clerk_code, cancel.sba_text
FROM canceled cancel
LEFT JOIN reservation res ON cancel.reservation_number = res.reservation_number
LEFT JOIN clients client ON res.home_client_code = client.client_code
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, cancel.cancel_date_time, cancel.arrival_date) < 21
        AND (cancel.arrival_date BETWEEN ? AND ?)
```

If I change the last line to `AND (cancel.arrival_date BETWEEN '2019-12-01' AND '2019-12-10')` it works fine.

I have also tried using `AND (cancel.arrival_date >= ? AND cancel.arrival_date <= ?)` which didn't work either, same error.

Comment: Are you literally checking `cancel.arrivale_date` against a `?` that does not seem like valid sql, there needs to be a date or a parameter, unless `?` means something in sql that I have not seen before, hence why it works when you add a real date `'2019-12-01'`

Comment: @chrisbyte this is a SQL query in Excel. `?` is used to signify a parameter where you can, at least in my case, select a cell value to use in place of the `?`.

Comment: My apologies I misread! I thought you were adapting this query for use outside of excel.

Comment: It could be the sub query in your SELECT statement causing the issue. According to this post sub queries aren't allowed in MS Query. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16722509/multipart-identifier-error-in-excel-2007-ms-query-but-not-in-sql-server-2008)